# Left join not being optimized

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, sql-optimization

On a SQL Server database, consider a classical parent-child relation like the following:

```
create table Parent(
p_id uniqueidentifier primary key,
p_col1 int,
p_col2 int
);

create table Child(
c_id uniqueidentifier primary key,
c_p uniqueidentifier foreign key references Parent(p_id)
);

declare @Id int
set @Id = 1
while @Id <= 10000
begin
insert into Parent(p_id, p_col1, p_col2) values (NEWID(), @Id, @Id);
set @Id=@Id+1;
end
insert into Child(c_id, c_p) select NEWID(), p_id from Parent;
insert into Child(c_id, c_p) select NEWID(), p_id from Parent;
insert into Child(c_id, c_p) select NEWID(), p_id from Parent;
;
```

Now I have these two equivalent queries, one using inner and the other using left join:

Inner query:

```
select *
from Child c
inner join Parent p
on p.p_id=c.c_p
where p.p_col1=1 or p.p_col2=2;
```

Left Join query:

```
select *
from Child c
left join Parent p
on p.p_id=c.c_p
where p.p_col1=1 or p.p_col2=2;
```

I thought that the sql optimizer would be smart enough to figure out the same execution plan for these two query, but it's not the case.
The plan for the inner query is this:
[image]

The plan for the left join query is this:
[image]

The optimizer works nice, chosing the same plan, if I have only one condition like:

```
where p.p_col1=1
```

But if I add an "or" on a second different column then it doesn't chose the best plan anymore:

```
where p.p_col1=1 or p.p_col2=2;
```

Am I missing something or it is just the optimizer that is missing this improvement?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Unfortunatly, "OR" operator isn't quite performant in SQL. 
If optmisation is a issue. You can rewrite it with an union and it will be more optimized.

`SELECT  *
FROM Child c
LEFT JOIN Parent p ON p.p_id=c.c_p
WHERE p.p_col1=1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM Child c
JEFT JOIN Parent p ON p.p_id=c.c_p
WHERE p.p_col2=2`

Comment: @AXMIM I will keep in mind when working with slow "or" conditions, fortunately in this case "inner" is the solution.

Comment: Why do you think it makes any difference which plan is used for your test data?

Comment: @philipxy Because in the second plan (left join), the filter is applied after the join between all the parents and the children (and this on millions of record takes minutes), in the first plan the join is applied only between the matching parents and the children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, it is the optimizer.

When you have one condition in the `WHERE` clause (and "condition" could be a condition connected with `AND`s, but not `OR`s), then the optimizer can easily peak and say "yes, the condition has rows from the second table, there is no `NULL` value comparison, so this is really an inner join".

That logic gets harder when the conditions are connected by `OR`.  I think you have observed that the optimizer does not do this for more complex conditions.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation, I will have much less faith in optimisers after this, especially when using "or" clauses.

Comment: @Gainder . . . Personally, I think I can do a better job than most optimizers.  But then again, by the time I've found what I think is the best query plan, most queries have already finished running.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you change the order of the conditions the generated plans are different. The optimizer won't check all possible implementation scenarios (unfortunately). That is why sometimes you have to use hints for optimization.